# Create a data structure that takes in key,value pairs and sorts out the data by value

Tags: c++

I was asked this question during an interview with BLOOMBERG and I honestly dont know how to answer it. Heres the question:
You are supposed to create a trading program. This program will receive all company name, stock value information everyday. Given this data, you need to create a function called "getKTopCompanies(k)" which will return all the top k companies currently.

I had an approach of storing all the companies along with their initial prices in an ordered map: map
However, the orders pairs by keys and not values.
Furthermore, I cannot just store the data in a priority queue because if I receive an update on the company stock in the future, I have to update it in the priority queue and pqs dont offer random access. Also, runtime has to be O(k) for finding the top k companies.

I guess my main question is that: is there a data structure that maintains unique keys and sorts the keys by their values?

For example:

```
Day 1:
[APPLE, 500]
[MCFST, 200]
[GOOG, 100]
[UBER, 750]
[FB, 350]

if you did getKTopCompanies(3)
This would print: UBER, APPLE, FB

Day 2:
[APPLE, 200]
[LYFT, 600]

if you did getKTopCompanies(3)
This would print: UBER, LYFT, FB
```

And so on.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How about a `std::map` with the stock price as the key and the company name as the value?

Comment: Boost.BiMap or Boost.MultiIndex come to mind. Or sqlite.

Comment: @PaulSanders dangerous if the stock price of two companies is equal.

Comment: Or using just standard containers, a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` and a `std::multimap<int, std::string>`. On inserts or updates, see if the company already exists in the map, and remove its entry from the multimap if so, then reinsert it with the new value.

Comment: O(k)??? Can we assume that keeping the datastructure sorted doesn't count for? We'd need to consider that possibly all prices get updated from one day to another...

Comment: @Shawn how does this guarantee O(k) time for the getTopK companies part of the problem? Would you mind expanding on your idea please?

Comment: Iterating through all the elements of a map is `O(N)`, so just the first k elements would be `O(k)`? I *think* that's what it's wanting.

Comment: On more thought, mapping names to the current iterator of that stock in the multimap is simpler and saves some lookups for inserts/updates. See updated answer.

Comment: @shawn, take a look at my answer below. It seems we use the same concept, but mine uses less resources.

Comment: @AKL If you need to sort as part of getting the top k elements like yours does it doesn't meet the complexity requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic question in many interviews. The problem is order a vector of pairs based in the first or second key. If you insert all the pairs at the begginning you can use a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>>` and the `std::sort()`. In the `std::sort` you can define a function that return a `bool` type to define an order.

But, if you insert pairs any time, then, a `std::list` is better than a `std::vector`. This because insert operation, keeping order, in the list is constant vs. the insert in a vector where probably it does some memory reallocation in the vector internals.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I sort the vector with every insert? Because then my insertion degrades to O(nlog n). Note that this question requires fastest possible insertion/update and fastest possible way of retrieving the top k companies

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a vector of pair, sort them according to the int, which is the value. 
If the values change, just use the swap function of the vector class, or simply call std::sort.
To get the first n values, call std::begin() - std::begin() + n.

Comment: For the vector of pair, if the value changes you have to re-sort all the n companies. The idea you are suggesting is maintaining a sorted vector of pairs. The problem with this is that if I decide to insert some company whose stock price is exactly in the middle, I will have to move over the other companies which is O(n). Insertion into a vector is O(n), therefore inserting n companies will be O(n^2) in the worst case which is terrible. Note that we have to optimize both insertion/update of companies and getting the top k companies

Comment: I have added another answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a custom type around `std::multimap`.

```
class StockPriceTracker
{
public:
    StockPriceTracker() = default;
    StockPriceTracker(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, std::string>> values) :
        m_record(values)
    {};

    void addOrUpdatePrice(std::string company, int price)
    {
        if (auto it = std::find_if(m_record.begin(), m_record.end(), [&](auto&& p) { return p.second == company; });
            it != m_record.end())
            m_record.erase(it);

        m_record.emplace(price, std::move(company));
    }

    auto getTopK(std::size_t k)
    {
        k = std::min(k, m_record.size());
        return RangeView(m_record.begin(), std::next(m_record.begin(), k));
    }

private:
    std::multimap<int, std::string, std::greater<int>> m_record;
};
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/gtu5fS) is a full example. `RangeView` is just a small wrapper that the function can be used in a range-based for loop. `getTopK` is O(1) but `addOrUpdatePrice` is O(n) (because of the duplicate check).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the approach I mentioned in a comment, using `std::multimap` to index by value and a `std::unordered_map` to index by name to find the position in the multimap (for efficiency so you don't have to scan the multimap on every insert or update to find the appropriate element):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

struct stock_info {
  std::string name;
  int value;
  stock_info(std::string n, int v) : name(std::move(n)), value(v) {}
};

class tracker {
public:
  void add(const std::string &name, int val);
  std::vector<stock_info> top_k(int k) const;

private:
  using stockmap = std::multimap<int, std::string>;  
  std::unordered_map<std::string, stockmap::iterator> byname;
  stockmap byvalue;
};

void tracker::add(const std::string &name, int val) {
  auto it = byname.find(name);
  if (it == byname.end()) { // Stock doesn't exist; add it.
    byname.emplace(name, byvalue.emplace(val, name));
  } else {
    // Update existing record by erasing current one and re-adding with new value.
    byvalue.erase(it->second);
    it->second = byvalue.emplace(val, name);
  }
}

std::vector<stock_info> tracker::top_k(int k) const {
  std::vector<stock_info> ret;
  ret.reserve(k);
  for (auto it = byvalue.crbegin(); k > 0 && it != byvalue.crend(); --k, ++it) {
    ret.emplace_back(it->second, it->first);
  }
  return ret;
}

void top3(const tracker &t) {
  for (const auto &s : t.top_k(3)) {
    std::cout << s.name << '\t' << s.value << '\n';
  }
}

int main(void) {
  tracker t;

  std::cout << "Day 1\n";
  t.add("APPLE", 500);
  t.add("MCFST", 200);
  t.add("GOOG", 100);
  t.add("UBER", 750);
  t.add("FB", 350); 
  top3(t);

  std::cout << "Day 2\n";
  t.add("APPLE", 200);
  t.add("LYFT", 600);
  top3(t);

  return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -O -Wall -Wextra mi.cpp
$ ./a.out
Day 1
UBER    750
APPLE   500
FB  350
Day 2
UBER    750
LYFT    600
FB  350
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>


int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> container;
    std::vector<decltype(container)::iterator> rank;

auto newEntry = [&](std::pair<std::string, int> value)
{
    container.insert(value);
    rank.emplace_back(container.find(value.first));
};

auto update = [&]() {
    std::sort(rank.begin(), rank.end(),
      [&](decltype(container)::iterator &first, decltype(container)::iterator &second) {
          return first->second > second->second;
    });
};

auto getTop = [&](unsigned k)
{
    return std::make_pair(rank.begin(), rank.begin() + k);
};

auto getTopPrint = [&](unsigned k)
{
    auto range = getTop(k);
    while (range.first != range.second)
    {
        std::cout << (*range.first)->first << " " << (*range.first)->second << '\n';
        range.first++;
    }
};

newEntry({"APPLE", 500});
newEntry({"MCFST", 200});
newEntry({"GOOG", 100});
newEntry({"UBER", 750});
newEntry({"FB", 350});

// Day 1:
update();
getTopPrint(3);


// Day 2:
std::cout << "\nDay2\n";
newEntry({"LYFT", 600});
container["APPLE"] = 200;
update();
getTopPrint(3);

return 0;
```

}

Now no work is handled at runtime, except printing the values. The program just has to update itself time to time, if any value is changed. Inserting is easier and printing k values has O(k) complexity.